# What is the purpose of shared folder in asp.net MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know what is the shared folder for in MVC,
does it to keep any special views?
Does it effect any content and codes in whole project.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_folders.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is merely a convention to say that these views will be "Shared" with other portions of the project(Controllers/Other Views/etc). You can put these views anywhere you would like as long as you reference them correctly.

Comment: What should go in the shared folder and what shouldn't?